# Box2d body 'vibrates' when it is in contact with static object

Tags: libgdx, box2d

following Situation: I have a box2d Body which I control via the accelerometer in a Zero gravity environment. I set linearVelocity proportional to 'roll' and 'pitch' via Impulses.
When the Body touches anything, it will cause damage.

Now the Problem: When the Body is colliding with static objects, and the direction of the movement is still pointing in that direction, the Body will still receive damage due to the Impulses (Body vibrating).

I tried to slow down the Body after collision, e.g. decreasing Maximum Impulse value over time(which works), but I'd rather don't want to slow it down.

Any suggestions how this could be achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should set a proper values for [Fixture](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Fixture.html) - in this case you should set `restitution` to 0.

```
    FixtureDef fd = new FixtureDef();
    fd.restitution = 0;
```

The `restitution` is abount how "bouncy" is body. The situation you've described is probably caused by too high restitution (body touches static one, bounce but immediately fall down due to gravity then bounce then...)

You can read more at [Box2D official reference](http://box2d.org/manual.pdf)

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I've just checked that. Unfortunately, all restitution values are explicitly set to 0. Maybe it's because I have a more complex Body. It contains two Springs (Distance joints) and a revolute joint? I'll post a sketch when at home

Comment: Here it is: [link](http://imgur.com/T7KDbl7)  The grey rectangle is a helper which has zero density and is not colliding at all. I manipulate it's angle to make the main body 'tilt'. Blue lines are distance joint configured as springs